# SQL Server XQuery.modify syntax issues, unable to resolve

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a SQL Server 2016 table `dbo.Agent` which has a column called `XMLDta`, but its datatype is `nvarchar(max)`.

The data within this column is structured as XML, like so:

```
<misc id="m12345">
  <pauth id="p12345">
    <AEmail/>
    <ipauth id="i12345">
      <IProd>xxxxxx</IProd>
      <achannel id="00000000">
        <Chan>ABCEDF</Chan>
        <Selected>1</Selected>
      </achannel>      
      <Seg>ZZZ</Seg>
      <states id="s12345">
        <Sel>0</Sel>
        <Avail>1</Avail>
        <State>XX</State>
      </states>
      <states id="s67890">
        <Sel>1</Sel>
        <Avail>1</Avail>
        <State>YY</State>
      </states>    
      <LOB>FFFF</LOB>
      <AUW>abc@email.com</AUW>
      <WQue>10</WQue>
      <AgChan>ABCEDF,</AgChan>
      <State>XX,YY,</State>
      <Status>Active</Status>
    </ipauth>
    <ipauth>
      ....
    </ipauth>
  </pauth>
</misc>
```

Trying to modify the `Status` node in above xml using following `XQuery.modify()` SQL/XQuery statement:

```
UPDATE dbo.Agent
SET CAST(xmldta AS xml).modify('replace value of (/misc/pauth/ipauth/Status/text()) with "Pending"')
WHERE agID = 209
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

Also tried using this SQL:

```
DECLARE @Dta As XML
DECLARE @id AS INT = 209

SELECT @Dta = CAST(XMLDta AS XML) 
FROM dbo.Agent 
WHERE agID = @id

UPDATE dbo.Agent
SET @Dta.modify('replace value of (/misc/pauth/ipauth/Status/text()) with "Pending"')
WHERE agID = 209
```

But I still get the same error:

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

How do I correctly structure my SQL statement so it can reference the `XMLDta` column within the `XQuery.modify` function?

Please remember `XMLDta` column has a datatype of `nvarchar(max)` in the `dbo.Agent` table.

If I am going about this wrong way, please let me know and suggest better path.

Thanks and any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Rebecca

Comment: If it's XML why is it not an `xml` column in the first place?

Comment: Guessing to conserve space on database.  We don't have control over tables being referenced...data comes from an external source system.

Comment: The `XML` datatype would use **less space** than storing the textual XML representation in a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column ....

Comment: It's an `nvarchar(MAX)`; it's certainly not saving space. Every character would use 2 bytes.

Comment: You can't use `.modify` unless you are referring directly to an `xml` column. One more good reason to change this column to `xml`

Comment: Thanks Charlieface, appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

Please take into account that the SQL Server XQuery `.modify()` method will update just one single XML element at a time.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata  NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<misc id="m12345">
    <pauth id="p12345">
        <AEmail/>
        <ipauth id="i12345">
            <IProd>xxxxxx</IProd>
            <achannel id="00000000">
                <Chan>ABCEDF</Chan>
                <Selected>1</Selected>
            </achannel>
            <Seg>ZZZ</Seg>
            <states id="s12345">
                <Sel>0</Sel>
                <Avail>1</Avail>
                <State>XX</State>
            </states>
            <states id="s67890">
                <Sel>1</Sel>
                <Avail>1</Avail>
                <State>YY</State>
            </states>
            <LOB>FFFF</LOB>
            <AUW>abc@email.com</AUW>
            <WQue>10</WQue>
            <AgChan>ABCEDF,</AgChan>
            <State>XX,YY,</State>
            <Status>Active</Status>
        </ipauth>
        <ipauth>....</ipauth>
    </pauth>
</misc>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @Dta AS XML
    , @param VARCHAR(30) = 'Pending'
    , @id AS INT = 1;

SET @Dta = (SELECT TRY_CAST(xmldata AS XML) FROM @tbl WHERE ID = @id);

SET @Dta.modify('replace value of (/misc/pauth/ipauth/Status/text())[1] with sql:variable("@param")');

UPDATE @tbl
SET xmldata = TRY_CAST(@Dta AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
WHERE ID = 1;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: Thanks so very much Miriamka for your response...appreciate your input.  Will give your suggestion a try.